# check if a person is within a zone by gps data

Tags: gps

I need to find if a person is located within the given zone by user's current GPS location (latitude and longitude).

For instance, I have a user GPS location and how do I find out which zone he is at?

[image]

Any API service able to do that? How to map the zone area?

Comment: it's called geolocation and/or geofencing. we're not here to find apis for you, but those two keywords should help your search.

Comment: if you only have the gps cooridnate you can do nothing. Of course you need the zone border coordinates.

Comment: if have zone border coordinate, how to tell if the person is within that zone?